# error in join using pig

Tags: join, apache-pig

I have used the following commands

```
X1 = LOAD '/PIG10/' using PigStorage(',') as (statename:chararray,district:chararray,code:chararray,ru:chararray);
Y1 = LOAD '/POP2/' using PigStorage(',') as (district:chararray,r_u:chararray);
```

I have the data as following in X1 with four columns

```
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    JAMMU & KASHMIR 00000   Total,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    JAMMU & KASHMIR 00000   Rural,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    JAMMU & KASHMIR 00000   Urban,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Kupwara 00000   Total,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Kupwara 00000   Rural,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Kupwara 00000   Urban,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Badgam  00000   Total,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Badgam  00000   Rural,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Badgam  00000   Urban,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Leh(Ladakh) 00000   Total,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Leh(Ladakh) 00000   Rural,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Leh(Ladakh) 00000   Urban,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Kargil  00000   Total,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Kargil  00000   Rural,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Kargil  00000   Urban,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Punch   00000   Total,,,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Punch   00000   Rural,,,)
```

In Y1 as following

```
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Total,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Rural,)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR    Urban,)
(Kupwara    Total,)
(Kupwara    Rural,)
(Kupwara    Urban,)
(Badgam Total,)
(Badgam Rural,)
(Badgam Urban,)
(Leh(Ladakh)    Total,)
(Leh(Ladakh)    Rural,)
(Leh(Ladakh)    Urban,)
(Kargil Total,)
(Kargil Rural,)
(Kargil Urban,)
(Punch  Total,)
(Punch  Rural,)
(Punch  Urban,)
(Rajouri    Total,)
(Rajouri    Rural,)
(Rajouri    Urban,)
```

I have used join  follows
C2 = join X1 by district,Y1 by district;
but I am unable to get the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, all your inputs are loaded into first column and the remaining 3 columns(district,code,ru) in X1 and 1 column(r_u) in Y1 is empty. 
Its looks like the delimiter ',' doesn't suit for your input data. Can you paste your actual input format of file PIG10 and POP2?

```
    Solution:
    Try this script, the below regex is written based on the above input only.
    X = LOAD '/PIG10/' AS line;
    Y = LOAD '/POP2/' AS line1;
    X1 = FOREACH X GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '(\\w+|\\w+\\s+&\\s+\\w+)\\s+([a-zA-Z()]+|\\w+\\s+&\\s+\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)')) AS (statename:chararray,district:chararray,code:chararray,ru:chararray);
    Y1 = FOREACH Y GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line1, '([a-zA-Z()]+|\\w+\\s+&\\s+\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)')) AS (district:chararray,r_u:chararray);
    C2 = join X1 by district,Y1 by district;
    DUMP C2;

Sample output:
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Punch,00000,Total,Punch,Rural)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Punch,00000,Total,Punch,Urban)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Badgam,00000,Urban,Badgam,Rural)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Badgam,00000,Urban,Badgam,Total)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Badgam,00000,Urban,Badgam,Urban)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Leh(Ladakh),00000,Urban,Leh(Ladakh),Rural)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Leh(Ladakh),00000,Urban,Leh(Ladakh),Total)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,Leh(Ladakh),00000,Urban,Leh(Ladakh),Urban)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,JAMMU & KASHMIR,00000,Rural,JAMMU & KASHMIR,Urban)
(JAMMU & KASHMIR,JAMMU & KASHMIR,00000,Rural,JAMMU & KASHMIR,Rural)
```

Comment: Hi yaar I figured it out I used delimiter in writing the output like store output in pig using PigStorage(',');